# Using Beautiful Soup on the heroku Application

Tags: github, heroku, beautifulsoup, discord

I am trying to deploy a bot I made in Python using the following libraries:
requests, beautifulsoup4, discord.

This is to be deployed using I believe git hub and Heroku. The bot deploys successfully; however, when I check the logs, the bot has crashed. Here is the error message:

```
2020-05-17T23:17:42.624634+00:00 app[api]: Deploy 83c32a30 by user ****************************
2020-05-17T23:17:42.624634+00:00 app[api]: Release v12 created by user ****************************
2
2020-05-17T23:17:43.134443+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2020-05-17T23:17:48.338694+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from starting to up
2020-05-17T23:17:51.764352+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from up to crashed
2020-05-17T23:17:51.660991+00:00 app[worker.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2020-05-17T23:17:51.661016+00:00 app[worker.1]: File "BocoBot_Version1.py", line 126, in <module>
2020-05-17T23:17:51.661182+00:00 app[worker.1]: soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')
2020-05-17T23:17:51.661184+00:00 app[worker.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/bs4/__init__.py", line 245, in __init__
2020-05-17T23:17:51.661401+00:00 app[worker.1]: % ",".join(features))
**2020-05-17T23:17:51.661423+00:00 app[worker.1]: bs4.FeatureNotFound: Couldn't find a tree builder with the features you requested: lxml. Do you need to install a parser library?**
2020-05-17T23:17:57.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
```

I believe this is the issue in question:

```
bs4.FeatureNotFound: Couldn't find a tree builder with the features you requested: lxml. Do you need to install a parser library?
```

But I do not know what I need to do to resolve it. My guess is that it has to do with my requirements.txt file where I tell it what packages to add. But no matter what changes I make to BeautifulSoup4, it continues not to work.

Here is the requirements.txt file information:

```
git+https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py
PyNaCl==1.3.0
pandas
beautifulsoup4
requests
discord
dnspython==1.16.0
async-timeout==3.0.1
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated and I will be happy to add more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding `lxml` to your `requirements.txt`.

Comment: Welp! that did it. I had always thought it was a part of Beautiful Soup. Thanks!

Comment: No worries! Really glad to hear you got it working - always a milestone to get 24/7 hosting :) Good luck!